# Webcam output issue opencv

Tags: python, string, image, opencv, image-processing

I'm working on a object detection programme with orb from frames captured by webcam .. I wonder how I can stream the output on full screen of my laptop. 
For now I'm getting this and a lot of data are Hidden since the output size is to small.
I'm also wondering how I can output the character in different lines . I've tried "\n" and it's not working.[image]

Comment: Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), "What Are Good Topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).